# I have created a search function using php and mysql but it will only search one word? how can i make it search a phrase

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a search function but it only works by entering in one key word. How can I let someone enter in a phrase and it will display results? at the minute im having to use _ and telling customers to use _ instead of space.

```
    <div class="post">
    <h1 class="title">Search Results for: <?php echo $_POST['keywords']; ?></h1>
    <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    $searchterm = $_POST['keywords'];

    include 'db.inc.php';
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE keywords like '%$searchterm%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large"><a href="./<?php echo $row['link']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>


    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is now **deprecated**. Please take a look at either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Why do your users have to use _ ?

Comment: Probably script is replacing all special chars (also spaces) with `_` in keywords before inserting. Check it in database by selecting all rows.

Comment: If these are just keywords, then split words and make a query like `keywords like '%$searchterm%' OR keywords like '%$searchterm2%' OR ...`. If you want a better text search, then read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: `$searchterm = str_replace(" ", "_", $_POST['keywords']);`